# build Microsoft Maps Spatial Toolbox from Visual Studio 2013 on win 7

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio, windows-7, bing-maps

I am trying to build **Microsoft Maps Spatial Toolbox** from Visual Studio 2013  on win 7.

The code was downloaded from

https://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/

But, it requires win 8.1. My machine is win 7.

Is there a workaround to build it on win 7 ?

If only WPF example can be built on win 7, that would also be fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create a new empty solution in VS 2013, and then add references to the individual projects that you want to use. In this case the WPF project. Alternatively, go into the WPF samples folder, and open the project of the sample you want in VS 2013. You likely will have a few other projects that won't load, just ignore those. It should still build. I ran into the same issue when I moved from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.